# Troubleshooting an iMac

Tags: macos, mac

What can I do to fix my iMac? When I start it up, it just loads forever (never getting to the Desktop). The mouse will appear then disappear, then the loading bar will sometimes appear and then disappear and it just goes in circles forever. If I start up in safe mode (by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>), it gets to the login window. However, if I attempt to log in the login window disappears and reappears asking for my password again.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about your machine? PPC vs Intel?  Its age? Any recent upgrades or changes to hardware?  Which operating system?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You have got a CD with your imac which contains various tools. Boot from that CD and check your harddisk for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up in [single user or verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492). If you can get into single user mode, try [running fsck](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417) - type `/sbin/fsck -fy` at the command line.

Alternatively, try restarting your computer from your system CD (hold down 'c' during start up). You can then use Disk Utility to check your hard drive, and if you can't get it fixed, re-install your system.